# How to efficiently manage multiple asynchronous tasks with error handling in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

I'm working on a Node.js project that involves performing multiple asynchronous tasks (API calls, database queries, etc.) concurrently. I want to ensure that my code is efficient and maintainable, while also handling errors properly.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
async function performTask1() {
    // Perform an API call or a database query
}

async function performTask2() {
    // Perform another API call or a database query
}

async function performTask3() {
    // Perform yet another API call or a database query
}

async function main() {
    // Execute performTask1, performTask2, and performTask3 concurrently
    // Handle errors for each task individually, without stopping the others
    // Wait for all tasks to complete before moving on
}

main();
```

I've looked into using Promise.all(), but it seems to reject as soon as any of the promises reject, which isn't what I want. I'd like to be able to handle errors for each task individually and still wait for all tasks to complete.

What's the best way to manage multiple asynchronous tasks like this, with proper error handling and efficiency in mind? Any suggestions or best practices are greatly appreciated!

How to efficiently manage multiple asynchronous tasks with error handling in Node.js?

Comment: `Promise.all([performTask1().catch(err => console.error("task1 failed", err)), performTask2().catch(err => console.error("task2 failed", err)), …])`

Comment: How *do* you actually *handle* the errors from the individual tasks?